# How to measure the wavelengths of ultraviolet lines in the hydrogen spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, radiation, hydrogen

how to measure the wavelengths of ultraviolet radiation isn't it invisible?
it's possible to measure visible radiation but how to measure invisible radiation?

Answer (score 2):

It's common to measure spectra in the non-visible region and UV or infra-red spectrometers are available off the shelf. Google for many, many manufacturers of the kit. Also see the Wikipedia articles on [UV spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet%E2%80%93visible_spectroscopy) and [infrared spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_spectroscopy).

Typically UV and IR spectrometers will use a diffraction grating to disperse the light and a photomultiplier tube to detect the radiation.

Answer (score 2):

Three different ways (at least).

1) Use a detector, like a photodiode or photomultiplier, which responds to UV by producing electrons when hit by photons even if those photons are not visible,

2) Use a detector, like a bolometer, which measures the temperature rise produced when UV energy is absorbed, or

3) Coat a visible-only detector with a phosphor which emits light when hit with UV, then detect the emitted visible light.